# Does JDK SwingWorker class pass GUI task to EDT automatically?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

Just want to know if jdk SwingWorker class will pass GUI related task to EDT for you or not?

Comment: When asking if something does something, it's usually much easier to comprehend the question if you give a (hypothetical) demonstration of the thing you think it might do.

Comment: Your question is too broad. See [*Worker Threads and SwingWorker*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for details that might help you focus.